# Verifying if a word exist inside my content

Tags: php

Im trying to give a class "margin" to my img if my content have less than 1100 chars and also if my content have inside a tag `<object>`.

Im having sucess verifying the number of chars of my content but Im not having sucesso verifying if `<object>` tag is inside or not content.

Do you see what Im doing wrong?

```
while ($result= $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $count= strlen($result['content']);
    $margin = ($count< 1100 && strpos('<object>', $result['content']) ? 'margin' : '');
    echo '<img class="img '.$margin.'" src="'.BASE.'/uploads/images/'.$result['img'].'"/>';
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while ($result= $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $count= strlen($result['content']);
    $margin = ($count< 1100 && strpos($result['content'], '<object>') ? 'margin' : '');
    eecho '<img class="img '.$margin.'" src="'.BASE.'/uploads/images/'.$result['img'].'"/>';
 }
```

invert in strpos function $result['content'] with object tag

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you use "eecho" and not "echo" to print, if you change this, it will works

Comment: Thanks, but dont works! That eecho was just a distraction when I did the question. I update it now!

Comment: This is my test code,   <?php

$str = "dsàgnsdfgfffffffffffffffffffffffffbisdfehpèogkifphnèdgfùnphè,dgfhnèdmgfkn<object>asdlkhnaslgfkndsgfklngòbdfsòk ";
    $count= strlen($str);
    $margin = ($count< 1100 && strpos($str, '<object>') ? 'margin' : '');
    echo '<img class="img '.$margin.'" src=""/>';
?>

Comment: Try it, and tell me if it is the behavior that you desire

Comment: As per my own answer below, you must use the strict comparison on strpos otherwise you will get a FALSE whenever the string starts with the <object>.

Answer (score 1):

If the `<object>` string starts at position 0 in the `$result['content']` it will return 0 which in your condition equates to FALSE which would not be what you want.

Therefore you should use:

```
strpos('<object>', $result['content'])!==false
```

So that finding the string at position 0 isn't confused with not finding the string at all (FALSE)